# Ввод данных в базу или модель не правильная модель БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

1.Создал модель погоды. Таблицы связаны с друг с другом. Синхронизировал модель с БД. Все делаю в Mysql Workbench

2.Теперь хотел бы протестировать созданную модель, проверить как она работает и работает ли. Хочу добавить данные:

- 26.06.2018 Температура 38, Скорость среднего ветра 10

Т.е. Значение таблицы Факт 26.06.2018, связать с таблицей Погода, значение  таблицы Погода связать с Элементом, который связан с таблицей Температура, а также с таблицей Ветер

3.Пытаюсь это сделать функцией insert, то эта функция дает возможность только заполнить значениями в одной таблице. При этом связать значение этой таблицы с другой не получается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить значение в таблицу, чтобы она была связана со значением другой таблицы?  ...или модель у меня просто неправильная, не могу понять. Подскажите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример связи таблиц:Таблица Fact связана через поле idfact с полем IdPogoda таблицы Pogoda
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас не хватает поля, по которому вы будите связывать. Т е в таблице pogoda должно быть поле id_fakt. И это поле нужно связать с idFuct

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц - таблицы у меня же связанные, через ID. Зачем еще добавлять поле?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц К примеру, таблица Fact связана (Foreign Key) с IdPogoda

Comment: когда вы будите вводить погоду, вы должны туда записать (в новую запись) ид элемента с таблицы Fact. Это нужно для связи

Comment: БД сама ничего связывать не будет. Это ваша задача корректно заполнить БД. т.е. вставляете insert запись в одну таблицу, получаете id только что созданной записи (например с помощью last_insert_id()), вставляете запись в следующую таблицу, при этом используете id который был получен на предыдущем этапе. P.S. специальные id для числовых значений выглядят очень странно. Чем вы будете заполнять TempAir, что 1 обозначает 20. А 2 обозначает 21 ? значение температуры проще использовать непосредственно

Comment: [тут пример гляньте](http://jtest.ru/bazyi-dannyix/sql-dlya-nachinayushhix-chast-3.html) у вас связь один ко многим. А то что у вас - один к одному (я думаю это не верно)

Comment: Подозреваю, что вся ваша задача может быть описана 2 таблицами: погода прогноз: id, дата, температура, влажность, данные ветра и погода факт: id, id-прогноза, дата, температура, влажность, данные ветра. но и это кажется избыточным. достаточно одной таблицы с данными с датой и признаком прогноз это или факт. связь по id не нужна вообще, по дате прекрасно можно сопоставить факт с прогнозом

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц В таблице Fact должна быть поле ID  погоды, а в таблице Pogoda поле Id Факта?

Comment: Нет, только в таблице pogoda. И вы это поле свяжите с полем id (fact)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц спасибо большое. Теперь понял!

Comment: @Mike спасибо за внимание к вопросу. Да думаю что так тоже можно. Но хотелось более структурировано хранить данные, с заделом на будущее. Вообще, нужно чтобы была возможность показывать погоду примерно такие варианты: 10.10.2018 на станции Температура 45, 10.10.2018 в районе Московской области наблюдается район с максимальным ветром 15 м\с и т.д.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц напишите отдельный коммент к вопросу, я его отмечу

Comment: @Kirumit У вас выходит структурированность ради структурированности. Работа с погодой обычно подразумевает очень большие массивы данных. А в системах с очень большими данными стараются вообще обходиться без join в запросах, потому что соединение двух таблиц слишком дорого. При вашей архитектуре начнутся проблемы с производительностью боюсь уже на жалкой сотне тысяч записей.

Comment: И главное, я не вижу какую гибкость можно получить если обозвать 20 единицей, а единицу двадцатью

Comment: @Mike спасибо за коммент. Да я тоже об том думал. В нашем случае обновление данных о погоде будет происходить только 1 раз в день. Кстати, если данные не структурировать, а все к примеру решить 3 таблицами, тогда будет много not null. Это нормально? Как считаете? Пример (при 3 таблицах): Пришли данные сегодня о температуре, завтра придут только о скорости ветра. Т.е. 28.10.2018, Температура 38, Скорость ветра 25, направление ветра not null, форма облаков not null, высота облаков not null ...

Comment: Вы видимо имели ввиду как раз NULL (а не not NULL). В принципе нормально, NULL для того и придуман что бы показать отсутствие данных. Тут вопрос в другом, если температура пришла 2 раза, а ветер только 1  можно ли эти данные по ветру точно отнести к одной и только одной температуре (т.е. понимать что вот эти измерения были выполнены вместе). Если нельзя непосредственно сопоставить, достаточно ли сопоставлять например по времени

Comment: @Mike Cопоставляются по месту измерению, дате, величине потом уже.

Comment: @Mike А ЗАЧЕМ СОПОСТАВЛЯТЬ ВЕТЕР И ТЕМПЕРАТУРУ? скорость ветра и направление ветра да нужно сопоставлять

Comment: Этого я не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю. Есть ли такая сущность например как "измерение". приходят ли данные сразу целым блоком или отдельно. т.е. придется ли апдейтить уже созданную запись. Нужно ли для каких то расчетов понимать связь температура-ветер или нет

Comment: @Mike спасибо за коммент. Да как раз думал над этим. Что придется апдейтить похоже. А если так. можете подсказать (так сказать, задать направление), как лучше реализовать тогда? Неужели каждый показатель, вынести в отдельную таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать в таблице pogoda поле `id_fact`. И вы это поле свяжите с полем id (fact)